# Merge Sort not happening correctly - Python

Tags: python, mergesort

Sorting is not happening correctly. Can some one help on sorting with this approach. Also please let me know where I am going wrong. I am new to Python so I am doing this myself. I am using the usual approach as we do in C or other languages.

```
base =[5,4,3,2,1]

def splitarray (low, high):
    if  low < high:
        mid = (high+low)/2

        splitarray (low, mid)
        splitarray (mid+1,high)
        merge(low,mid,high)

    else:
        return

def merge(low,mid,high):
    print("merge " +str(low) + " - " +str(mid)+" - "+ str(high))
    result = [0]*len(base)
    k = 0
    i=low
    j=mid+1
    l=0


    while i <= mid and j <= high:
        if (base[i] < base[j]):

            result[k]= base[i]
            k+=1
            i += 1

        if (base[i] > base[j])  :


            result[k]= base[j]

            j += 1
            k += 1





    while i <= mid:
        result[k]= base[i]
        k += 1
        i += 1
    while j <= high:
        result[k]= base[j]
        #count = count + mid - i
        j += 1
        k += 1

    print result

    l = low
    k= 0
    while l <= high:
        base[l] = result[l]
        l += 1


    print base
splitarray(0,len(base)-1)
```

Comment: Please include information about what exactly is going wrong, along with example inputs, expected outputs and actual results. Are you getting a traceback? (If so, include it in the question.) Badly sorted results? (If so, show the inputs and outputs.)

Comment: You don't want to use the builtin `sorted`?

Comment: Input is the array given above i.e base = [4,3,2,1] output should be [1,2,3,4]. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkDickinson if you execute the program you can see the wrong out out. Sorted input is in the code itself.

Comment: @Moses No. I am just implementing merge sort

Comment: I've just edited the code to add back in the `def` introducing your first function, which seems to have been edited out by mistake. This question would be *vastly* improved if you actually said what was going on when you run the code (e.g. does it crash, or give the wrong answer, and if the latter, what answer). While it is a self-contained example, many problems can be explained more easily if you just say what's happening! There's no hint in the question what you mean by "sorting is not happening correctly".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your current (updated) code appears to be with the last loop:

```
l = low
k= 0
while l <= high:
    base[l] = result[l]
    l += 1
```

Here you're copying the values from the `results` list to the `base` list. However, the results are all at the start of `results`, not at the same coordinates you want them to go in `base`. You seem to have *almost* got it right since you're setting `k` to zero, but you don't end up using `k` in the loop.

Try:

```
l = low
k= 0
while l <= high:
    base[l] = result[k]  # read the result from index k, not l
    l += 1
    k += 1  # increment k as well
```

This should work as intended. Note that while this will do the sorting correctly, this isn't a very elegant way of sorting in Python. To start with, you can only sort the one global variable `base`, not any list (it would be much nicer to pass the list as a parameter). However, since this looks like something you've written mostly for the learning experience, I'll leave further improvements up to you.

Comment: Yes. This worked. I tested with adding K, but missed to increment. I am aware that this approach is not making use of advantages of python. I will proceed as suggested. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Visually the way the algorithm operates is:[image]

So the most obvious way to implement merge sort is to return a new list for each merge. Maybe that can be optimized to what it seems like you're trying to do, which is to operate on a single top level `result`. But if you do it this way you can't just append to `result` at each level of merging. Because at the bottom level of the recursion you'll add four elements, then at the middle level you'll add four, then at the top level you'll add another four. It's too many. If you do it this way you should instead have a fixed `result` size and operate on its indices throughout the entire execution.

A second mistake is that you are reading through an unmodified `base` for every merge. The precondition at each merge step is that the two lists being merged are already sorted. If you're implementing the algorithm in the obvious way you can just use the return values from deeper merges. If you're implementing the algorithm in some optimized way using a top level `result`, then you should be reading from `result`, not `base`.

Comment: I found a very similar approach here. 
 [link]http://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/merge_sort_program_in_c.htm

Comment: In this code `a` is an ever changing results array. `b` is a temporary buffer used during each merge, which upon completion writes the relevant elements back to `a`. You seem to have mixed up the meaning of these variables

Comment: You are right. Altered the code. Not able to find what is going wrong now.